# How to clear onClick before add new onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I try to replace an onclick event with other onclick event with javascript:

```
<button id='myButton' onClick=""/>
```

**OLD onClick event :**

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    alert('1');
});
```

**and then i do the same like that and change the value of alert , i do like this :**

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    alert('2');
});
```

> The result of method above is alert show twice for 1 and 2. What i
>   want is only 2 that must show (i replace alert('1') with alert('2');
>   not add another alert. How to fix my code?

Comment: Why not just change what you alert..... I'm don't think I understand your question.... Maybe you're looking for something to unbind an event... and since you're using jQuery here's a relevant link for that http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: @NewToJS : so add $('#myButton').unbind(); before i add new onclick event right? if that your mean you can put it as answer. And i will accept as the correct answer cause your answer working well for me. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem has been solved. I use method unbind like explain from here :

```
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/
```

**For my case :**

```
$('#myButton').unbind("click");
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
$(document).off('click', '#myButton').on('click', '#myButton', function(){
    alert('2');
});
```

It will unbind previous event listener and add the new one.

Comment: How about if i use $('#myButton').unbind(); ? which one the better method to unbind ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 jQuery event listeners which listen same element. They know about element's id and this is enough for they work.

What I'm trying to say, that they don't care about `onClick`

You should code two JS functions, but not jQuery event listeners.

```
<button id='id' onClick="choose function"/>

function myFunction1() {
   //your code
}

function myFunction2() {
   //same
}
```